# .NET MAUI - Tabview Content use Binding Model for new page name

Tags: xaml, data-binding, maui, syncfusion

I currently have a Tab View which opens Content Views as separate Pages within the view.
I have bound the tabs and images and also have a bound item for the page to call, I am struggling on the marked line to use my bound value:

My Main ContentPage is as follows :

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="MauiApp1.StaticTabView"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp1"
             xmlns:page="clr-namespace:MauiApp1.View"
            xmlns:tabView="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.TabView;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.TabView"
            BackgroundColor="Black">
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:TabItemsSourceViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <tabView:SfTabView ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" TabBarHeight="72" >
        <tabView:SfTabView.HeaderItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Image Source="{Binding ImageName}" HeightRequest="72" WidthRequest="72"/>
                </StackLayout>    
            </DataTemplate>
        </tabView:SfTabView.HeaderItemTemplate>
        <tabView:SfTabView.ContentItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <page:test /> <!-- Here is my Issue I need to bind this value -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </tabView:SfTabView.ContentItemTemplate>    
    </tabView:SfTabView>    
</ContentPage>
```

For the Line I have a page called test which it calls, but I need this to be dynamic and bound:-

```
<page:test />
```

I was hoping or trying to put something like, which does not work I can not figure out how to get a bound value at this section. :-

```
<page: "{Binding PageName}" />
```

For the life of me I can not figure out how to do this :)

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: You are trying to bind to different pages? Use a DataTemplateSelector.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for the heads up, I read up on DataTemplateSelectors, but I can not see how I can use it with the Statement/code I have shown.  All of the references I have just read and viewed are similar to the Bindings I am currently Using. If you have a link with an example which would point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I forgot that DataTemplateSelector is only useful with a collection; can't be used where you just need a single DataTemplate. I'll write an answer that defines an IValueConverter. Untested; may need some changes to get it to work.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you, I am happy to read any links anything to point me and help me learn, just hit a stumbling block on this one, as not even sure as to why I can not get a value here.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I just researched IValueConverter, I am unsure if I have explained my problem clearly enough. The element <page: pagename /> Just requires a string value at pagename point, my binding has the pagename value in it, but that line of code I can not add any binding reference it will only accept a direct pagename.

Comment: Not possible. One way or another, you'll have to write c# code to generate the needed DataTemplate object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a string containing a page's name, make a DataTemplate containing an instance of that page.
This can be done using an IValueConverter.

Usage:

```xml
<ContentPage ...
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace"
             x:Class=... >
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <local:NameToPageTemplateConverter x:Key="nameToPageTemplateConverter" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    ...
    <tabView:SfTabView ...
        ContentItemTemplate="{Binding PageName, Converter={StaticResource nameToPageTemplateConverter}}"
        ... >
        <tabView:SfTabView.HeaderItemTemplate>
        ...
    </tabView:SfTabView>
```

where `PageName` is a property, in current BindingContext, similar to `ImageName`.

Declaration: a .cs file containing NameToPageTemplateConverter:

```cs
namespace YourNameSpace   <-- must match namespace in `xmlns:local` declaration above.
{
  public class NameToPageTemplateConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((string)value)
        {
            case "Page1":
                return new DataTemplate(typeof(Page1));
            case "Page2":
                return new DataTemplate(typeof(Page2));
            default:
                throw new InvalidProgramException("Unknown page name");
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Cheers Steve, that is excellent, I will work through. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain it so clearly.